# Pyrsistent transformation that allows missing fields

Tags: python, immutability, pyrsistent

I plan to replace quite complex JSON-like, mutable data structures with their `pyrsisent` equivalent in Python. I need to change the value belonging to a key if the key exists. In the test function at the end, you can see the test case that should work. The original version of my `convert_timeout_to_seconds` function fails because of the missing `timeout` field in the second `PMap` item.

I guess there should be a general solution for this problem, that uses the `transform` or a transform-like method, that doesn't raise an error, when a field is missing, just keeps that `PMap` as it is. I was able to come up with a version, that solves this particular problem, but in more difficult situations the lambda function can become very complicated. Is there a general solution?

```py
from pyrsistent import freeze, thaw, ny, PVector

def convert_timeout_to_seconds_original(action_list: PVector) -> PVector:
    " Original, that raises TypeError: int() argument must be ..., not 'PMap' "
    return action_list.transform((ny, "timeout"), int)

def convert_timeout_to_seconds(action_list: PVector) -> PVector:
    " Working version "
    return action_list.transform((lambda ix: "timeout" in action_list[ix], "timeout"), int)

def test_convert_timeout_to_seconds_missing_timeout():
    action_list = freeze([
        dict(timeout="13", description="send email"),
        dict(description="start database"),
    ])
    new_action_list = [
        dict(timeout=13, description="send email"),
        dict(description="start database"),
    ]
    result = convert_timeout_to_seconds(action_list)
    assert result == new_action_list
```

Answer (score 0):

This solutions work if the first parameter, the `structure` contains nested structures are made only from `PVector`s and `PMap`s. The `path` and `command` parameters are the same as in the `transform` method of pyrsistent structures.

```py
from typing import List, Callable, Union

from pyrsistent import PVector, PMap, ny, freeze


def loose_transform(structure: Union[PVector,PMap], path: List, command: Callable):
    if not path:
        return command(structure) if callable(command) else command
    key_spec = path[0]
    if not callable(key_spec):
        key_spec_original = key_spec
        key_spec = lambda ix: ix == key_spec_original
    if isinstance(structure, PVector):
        return freeze([
            loose_transform(item, path[1:], command) if key_spec(ix) else item
            for ix, item in enumerate(structure)
        ])
    return freeze({
        k: loose_transform(v, path[1:], command) if key_spec(k) else v
        for k, v in structure.items()
    })
```

For the unit tests I used [see this gist](https://gist.github.com/horvatha/92fe3adfd92723df38a65a641267a482).